# Loop through dictionary of dataframes and merge each dataframe in dictionary with a single dataframe, in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dataframes and I would like to merge each dataframe in said dictionary with a single dataframe that is not on that dictionary. After that I would like the merged dataframes to rewrite the ones in the dictionary.

So I have a dictionary thst cointains over 200 different dataframes:
`dictionary = {'df1' : df1 .... 'df200' : df200}`

In which each dataframe in the dictionary looks like this:

| DATE | Individual | Location | Money_Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-05-22 | 1 | Seattle | 10000 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | Chicago | 30000 |
| 2012-06-30 | 1 | Seattle | 10000 |
| 2021-10-22 | 1 | Los Angeles | 30000 |
| 2010-06-13 | 1 | Seattle | 10000 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | Chicago | 30000 |

Which is the dataframe df1 for individual 1. df2 in the dictionary is for individual 2 and has the same information but for individual 2:

| DATE | Individual | Location | Money_Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-05-02 | 2 | Atlanta | 50000 |
| 2009-01-14 | 2 | Chicago | 30000 |
| 2004-06-20 | 2 | Atlanta | 60000 |
| 2009-10-12 | 2 | Los Angeles | 80000 |
| 2017-07-23 | 2 | New York | 90000 |
| 2018-04-14 | 2 | Chicago | 100000 |

And so on for 200 individuals.

I would like to merge each df in the dictionary with another dataframe that is outside of the dictionary that looks like this:

| DATE | Location | CUMSUM Money Spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-06-30 | Atlanta | 10000000 |
| 2009-09-30 | Atlanta | 30000000 |
| 2020-06-30 | Atlanta | 55000000 |
| 2013-03-31 | Chicago | 670999999 |
| 2013-12-31 | New york | 600000 |
| 2018-03-31 | New york | 6500000 |
| 2013-12-31 | Los Angeles | 2300000 |
| 2018-03-31 | Los Angeles | 567000 |

This dataframe has the cumulative sum of the money spent each quarter in each location. I would like to merge each dataframe in the dictionary, with the dataframe that has info on the cumulative sum of money spent. I want to merge this dataframe on 'Location'. So each dataframe in the dictionary should have N rows with information on the money spent in a day, with N being the number of observation for each quarter in a given city.

For example, the dataframe related to the individual 2 has two obsevation related to the money spent in a day in Atlanta, and the dataframe with the cumulative money spent has 3 observations. So the merged dataframe should have 6 rows related to the Atlanta location. Final dataframe should look like this:

| DATE_x | Individuaial | Location | Money_Speny | Date_y | CUMSUM Money Spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-05-02 | 2 | Atlanta | 50000 | 2012-06-30 | 10000000 |
| 2012-05-02 | 2 | Atlanta | 50000 | 2009-09-30 | 30000000 |
| 2012-05-02 | 2 | Atlanta | 50000 | 2020-06-30 | 55000000 |
| 2004-06-20 | 2 | Atlanta | 60000 | 2012-06-30 | 10000000 |
| 2004-06-20 | 2 | Atlanta | 60000 | 2009-09-30 | 30000000 |
| 2004-06-20 | 2 | Atlanta | 60000 | 2020-06-30 | 55000000 |
| 2009-01-14 | 2 | Chicago | 30000 | 2013-03-31 | 670999999 |
| 2012-05-02 | 2 | Chicago | 50000 | 2013-03-31 | 670999999 |
| 2009-10-12 | 2 | Los Angeles | 80000 | 2013-12-31 | 2300000 |
| 2009-10-12 | 2 | Los Angeles | 80000 | 2018-03-31 | 567000 |
| 2017-07-23 | 2 | New york | 90000 | 2013-12-31 | 600000 |
| 2017-07-23 | 2 | New york | 90000 | 2018-03-31 | 6500000 |

I would like this new dataframe to replace the one in the dictionary, for each dataframe in the dictionary.

I have tried `for key, df in dict_df.items(): df = pd.merge(df, cumsum, on = 'Individual', how = 'right')`

But it says "TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'dict'> was passed"

Thank you.

Comment: how do you read in all of these dataframes? Why are there so many separate dataframes? For example, if you had 200 files for each individual that you read in, you might go with a different solution entirely. I.E. is there a specific need for so many dataframes VS. one dataframe with a column that differentiates the individuals.

Comment: I do have a dataframe that differentiates individuals, in fact I created the dictionary with that dataframe. I have so many different dataframes because I need to create reports based on individuals and cities. I already created a function to create this report based on the cities, but now I want to create this report for each individual in each in city, with a different report for each combination of city and individual. The final product should just be a row in a dataframe, but I need to convert each dataframe in the dictionary first so I can apply the function I defined.

Comment: can you share all of your code? I may have an idea.

Comment: @tipatito then why not do this `before` splitting into multiple dataframes. It would be much more efficient

Comment: You may work directly with the big dataframe. You may need to check the merge doc: according to your example and doc it would be like to do  : bigdf.merge(cumsumdf, how='left', on='Location')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer `df1` is the entire dataframe ***before*** you separate into 200 dataframes. All you have to do is merge with the other dataframe, `dropna` and sort as desired. From there, you can split into multiple dataframes:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Location').dropna().sort_values(['Individual', 'Location', 'DATE_x', 'CUMSUM Money Spent'])
```

---

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': {0: '2010-05-22',
  1: '2021-01-04',
  2: '2012-06-30',
  3: '2021-10-22',
  4: '2010-06-13',
  5: '2021-03-04',
  6: '2012-05-02',
  7: '2009-01-14',
  8: '2004-06-20',
  9: '2009-10-12',
  10: '2017-07-23',
  11: '2018-04-14'},
 'Individual': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 2,
  9: 2,
  10: 2,
  11: 2},
 'Location': {0: 'Seattle',
  1: 'Chicago',
  2: 'Seattle',
  3: 'Los Angeles',
  4: 'Seattle',
  5: 'Chicago',
  6: 'Atlanta',
  7: 'Chicago',
  8: 'Atlanta',
  9: 'Los Angeles',
  10: 'New York',
  11: 'Chicago'},
 'Money_Spent': {0: 10000,
  1: 30000,
  2: 10000,
  3: 30000,
  4: 10000,
  5: 30000,
  6: 50000,
  7: 30000,
  8: 60000,
  9: 80000,
  10: 90000,
  11: 100000}})
df1


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': {0: '2012-06-30',
  1: '2009-09-30',
  2: '2020-06-30',
  3: '2013-03-31',
  4: '2013-12-31',
  5: '2018-03-31',
  6: '2013-12-31',
  7: '2018-03-31'},
 'Location': {0: 'Atlanta',
  1: 'Atlanta',
  2: 'Atlanta',
  3: 'Chicago',
  4: 'New york',
  5: 'New york',
  6: 'Los Angeles',
  7: 'Los Angeles'},
 'CUMSUM Money Spent': {0: 10000000,
  1: 30000000,
  2: 55000000,
  3: 670999999,
  4: 600000,
  5: 6500000,
  6: 2300000,
  7: 567000}})

df2
```

---

Output:

```
Out[35]: 
        DATE_x  Individual     Location  Money_Spent      DATE_y  \
0   2021-01-04           1      Chicago        30000  2013-03-31   
1   2021-03-04           1      Chicago        30000  2013-03-31   
5   2021-10-22           1  Los Angeles        30000  2018-03-31   
4   2021-10-22           1  Los Angeles        30000  2013-12-31   
11  2004-06-20           2      Atlanta        60000  2012-06-30   
12  2004-06-20           2      Atlanta        60000  2009-09-30   
13  2004-06-20           2      Atlanta        60000  2020-06-30   
8   2012-05-02           2      Atlanta        50000  2012-06-30   
9   2012-05-02           2      Atlanta        50000  2009-09-30   
10  2012-05-02           2      Atlanta        50000  2020-06-30   
2   2009-01-14           2      Chicago        30000  2013-03-31   
3   2018-04-14           2      Chicago       100000  2013-03-31   
7   2009-10-12           2  Los Angeles        80000  2018-03-31   
6   2009-10-12           2  Los Angeles        80000  2013-12-31   

    CUMSUM Money Spent  
0            670999999  
1            670999999  
5               567000  
4              2300000  
11            10000000  
12            30000000  
13            55000000  
8             10000000  
9             30000000  
10            55000000  
2            670999999  
3            670999999  
7               567000  
6              2300000
```